# java jdbi3 withHandle delete not updating the DB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb, jdbi

I am using java JDBI3 to perform basic CRUD on mariaDB.
I am able to establish connection successfully.

The select * query from java works correctly.

```
jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle.createQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM users where email = :email;")
                .bind("email", email)

        );
```

Similarly when I try delete from it does not update the DB

```
jdbi.withHandle(handle -> {
                    return handle.createUpdate(
                            "DELETE FROM users WHERE email = :email;")
                            .bind("email", email)
                            .execute();
                }
        );
```

I tried to login in the sql shell and form there I am able to delete

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE email = 'dummy@email.com'
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `;` from your statement?

Comment: yes it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using "createUpdate" method as per its documentation: 
https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/Handle.html

> Create an Insert or Update statement which returns the number of rows
>   modified.

Instead, write

```
jdbi.withHandle(handle -> {
                    return handle.execute(
                            "DELETE FROM users WHERE email = :email",email);
                });
```

Comment: That's not right, take a look at this doc https://jdbi.org/#_statement_types